# PHP - Array not recognizing dollar amount with more than 3 figures

Tags: php, arrays, number-formatting

In my configuration file I have services defined as such:

```
$services = array(
              array("service1", "500"),
              array("service2", "1000"),
        );
$show_services = TRUE;
```

And this in my form processing file:

```
if($show_services){
        $amount = number_format($services[$service][1],2);
```

I get an error for any dollar amount item over $999 - saying that the item doesn't exist.
It seems like maybe the issue is in the number_format definition, but I am not skilled enough with php to know how to solve this. This is code that I purchased and modified for my own usage. It works perfectly except for this one issue.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Include the loop you're using to iterate over `$services`.

Comment: This syntax is correct and shouldn't throw an error: number_format(1000, 2); But that's what you have, so the error must be in your array. Post more code please.

Comment: did either of the two answers below help you out?  Please leave comments if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're referencing the service at the top array level.  You'll need to reference the second level.

the first block below doesn't work because you're referencing your array in a way that's different than how it's defined.  *Posting more code would definitely help here* because the way the original array is defined looks like this is an inefficient script.  It seems that you could define the array in a way that would not require looping.

The second block shows how to redefine your array so that it works with your code. and it works, no looping required.

```
<?

header( 'content-type: text/plain' );
$services = array(
              array("service1", "500"),
              array("service2", "1000"),
        );

$service = 'service1';

$amount = number_format( $services[$service][1],2 );
echo $amount . PHP_EOL;

$services['service1'] = array("service1", "500");
$services['service2'] = array("service2", "1000");
$service = 'service1';

$amount = number_format( $services[$service][1],2 );

echo $amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the numbers use this:

```
$services[0][1]
```

or:

```
$services[1][1]
```

the first number in the brackets should change, but the second should always stay [1].